# How to create a header (navbar) for webview which consists of a back button?

Tags: react-native, webview, react-navigation

In my React Native CLI App (Version 0.70 +), I am displaying a website using WebView (Version 11.26.0).

I want to show a navbar(header) only when the user can go back (i.e., on all screens except the home screen) and the header only contains a back button inside it, to the left.

What is the best way to implement this?

My code till now:

```
const App = () => {
  const webView = useRef();
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);

  const handleBack = useCallback(() => {
    if (canGoBack && webView.current) {
      console.log(canGoBack, webView.current);
      webView.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, [canGoBack]);

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    };
  }, [handleBack]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaView}>
       <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.KeyboardAvoidingView}>
          <WebView style={styles.webView}
            source={{
              uri: "<My URI>"
            }}
            onNavigationStateChange={navState => {
                setCanGoBack(navState.canGoBack)
                console.log({navState});
              }
            }
            ref={webView}
          </WebView>
       </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

I am not able to understand how to use https://reactnavigation.org/ for my exact usecase.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#page-navigation-gesture-and-button-support

this link maybe helpful

Answer (score 0):

add in the navigation stack of that page only; thats it

example:

```
 <Stack.Screen
    name="WebBooking"
    component={WebBooking}
    options={{headerShown: true, title: "Booking"}}
  />
```